# SVN Checkout of all the allowed folders

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

I have one svn project with 100 folders inside. But I don't have read access on all of them. Even the project level read access is not available. I can checkout each folder giving absolute path like the below:

> svn co svn+ssh://mysvn.company.com/myrepo/branches/Project1/Path1_Allowed

Is there any way I can checkout all the allowed folders and sub folders of a project in one go?

Comment: have you tried svn co svn+ssh://mysvn.company.com/myrepo/branches/Project1/* or svn co svn+ssh://mysvn.company.com/myrepo/branches/Project1/

Comment: Yes. It says access is denied as I don't have read access on the full Project1 folder. Only some folders inside Project1, I have access.